# Understanding variance components

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Suppose that a data frame `mydata` defined in R as below:

```
subj   task        value
20447   one   -0.0748662353
20447   two    0.1496499181
20973   one    0.0857235193
20973   two   -0.0717919692
21163   one   -0.0127782635
21163   two   -0.0276126750
21209   one   -0.0991728380
21209   two   -0.0366962068
21590   one    0.0877064988
21590   two   -0.1085537076
21606   one   -0.1079785675
21606   two   -0.0085944356
21728   one   -0.1930355579
21728   two    0.1854902506
22177   one    0.0097660916
22177   two   -0.0211494733
22380   one   -0.1674177796
22380   two    0.0207968391
22437   one    0.0772108734
22437   two   -0.2923604548
22481   one    0.2071408480
22481   two    0.0475899465
22542   one   -0.0521434657
22542   two   -0.0879639089
22660   one    0.1412477642
22660   two   -0.0117696403
22687   one   -0.0357611477
22687   two    0.0210354365
22717   one   -0.1884273887
22717   two   -0.0627750456
22774   one   -0.0081871208
22774   two   -0.1918840110
22819   one   -0.0174961872
22819   two    0.1478478014
22828   one    0.0877962410
22828   two    0.1598703414
22834   one   -0.0129472436
22834   two   -0.1461549848
22861   one   -0.0195148438
22861   two    0.1033238992
22881   one    0.1924221814
22881   two    0.0976813287
22959   one    0.0110813985
22959   two   -0.0699643195
23107   one   -0.0007286961
23107   two    0.0322275236
23154   one   -0.0368062854
23154   two    0.0869562626
23193   one    0.0394514129
23193   two   -0.0930772796
```

With the following model:

```
mydata$subj <- as.factor(mydata$subj)
library('lme4')
fm <- lmer(value ~ 1 + (1|task) + (1|subj), data=mydata)
```

I get the variance components below:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 subj     (Intercept) 0.0000  
 task     (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual             0.1096
```

The reason for this model is to compute intraclass correlation for 'task' and 'subj'. My confusion is: Why do I have a zero variance for both variables 'subj' and 'task'? Anything special about the model or the data?

Comment: Could it be because they are factors?

Comment: @ilanman Not so sure what you mean by the fact that both explanatory variables are factors. Do you mind elaborating it a little bit more?

Comment: Sure. I haven't looked into the `lmer` function, but just looking at the data: What is the variance of "one" "two" "one" "two"? There isn't really a concept of variance is there? $Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2]$. What is $E[X]$ for something that's not a number? Unless the variance you are referencing is not for the variable itself, but something else specific to `lmer`.

Comment: How was the data generated? Is it simulated?  If so, does it follow a random effects model?

Comment: @Andrew M It's actually real data, but truncated when displayed in R.

Comment: Seem nothing special. Just the variance components are close to zero.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang It's not obvious to me. So I'm still puzzled by this.

Comment: My understanding is that the true variance components are zero. `ranef(fm)` would output the estimates for random effects that are all zero. There seems no random effects at all. I can show some math derivations and code if that is what you expect to see.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Yes, `ranef(fm)` indeed does clearly show the random effects of all zero value! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~jcliu/paper/HierarchicalPrior.pdf, and the accompanying package [blme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blme/index.html)